# How do I write the class for an object that downloads image, but has a progress block and a completion block to broadcast the download?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, objective-c-blocks, nsurlsession

I'm new to block programming with Objective-C, and I searched to try to find an answer to this, so apologies if this is a silly question.

I'm writing a class to wrap [Imgur](http://imgur.com) downloads. It's a subclass of `NSObject` and uses `NSURLSession`. I'm using a singleton pattern to allow me to easily fire off a download in one line, and get the progress of the image download and the `UIImage` itself once completed.

```
- (void)downloadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)URL
              progressBlock:(void (^)(CGFloat percentageDownlaoded))progressBlock
          completionHandler:(void (^)(UIImage *downloadedImage, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))completionHandler;
```

But I'm confused how I implement this in the class itself. Here's my full class file:

```
+ (instancetype)sharedClient {
    static ImgurClient *sharedClient = nil;

    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        sharedClient = [[ImgurClient alloc] init];
    });

    return sharedClient;
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:[NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration] delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
    }

    return self;
}

#pragma mark - External Download Methods

/**
 * Asynchronously downloads the image for the given URL.
 */
- (void)downloadImageWithURL:(NSURL *)URL
              progressBlock:(void (^)(CGFloat percentageDownlaoded))progressBlock
          completionHandler:(void (^)(UIImage *downloadedImage, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))completionHandler {
}

/**
 * Asynchronously downloads the thumbnail for the given URL at the specified size.
 */
- (void)downloadThumbnailWithID:(NSURL *)URL
                           size:(CSImgurThumbnailSize)size
                  progressBlock:(void (^)(CGFloat percentageDownlaoded))progressBlock
              completionHandler:(void (^)(UIImage *downloadedImage, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error))completionHandler {
}

#pragma mark - NSURLSessionDelegate Methods

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite {
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didResumeAtOffset:(int64_t)fileOffset expectedTotalBytes:(int64_t)expectedTotalBytes {
}

- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didFinishDownloadingToURL:(NSURL *)location {
}
```

How do I go about structuring this class? Do I have properties representing the progress then throw that into the appropriate methods?

If anyone could shed any light or give a link to an explanation I'd greatly appreciate it.

Comment: This isn't directly related to your question, but I don't see any particular reason that you would use a singleton to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Here's parts of it in sketch form, I'll concentrate on one block to give you an idea, you'll have to fill in all the other parts yourself otherwise this answer will be huge.
You'll need to add properties to sharedClient to hold the blocks.

It will be much easier if you typedef the types of the blocks first i.e.

```
typedef void (^PercentageDownloadedBlock)(CGFloat percentageDownlaoded);
```

Then you can declare your property as

```
@property (copy, nonatomic)     PercentageDownloadedBlock   thePercentageBlock;
```

Then do something like this:

```
- (void)downloadThumbnailWithID:(NSURL *)URL
                           size:(CSImgurThumbnailSize)size
                  progressBlock:(PercentageDownloadedBlock)progressBlock
              completionHandler:(completionHandlerBlock)completionHandler
{
    self.thePercentageBlock = progressBlock;
    start the connection
    ...
}


- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didWriteData:(int64_t)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(int64_t)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(int64_t)totalBytesExpectedToWrite 
{
    CFFloat progress = do calculation of progress
    self.thePercentageBlock(progress);
    ...
}
```

etc.

Answer (score 1):

I already done that and wrap it in a subclass of NSURLConnection. Hope this help. Check it here:-

https://github.com/hackiftekhar/IQURLConnection

Following blocks have been implemented:-

1) `ResponseBlock` //NSURLResponse

2) `ProgressBlock` //Value range from 0.0 to 1.0

3) `CompletionBlock` //NSData, NSError

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at AFNetworking's [AFURLSessionManager](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFURLSessionManager.m) and [AFHTTPSessionManager](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking/blob/master/AFNetworking/AFHTTPSessionManager.m). It wraps the NSURLSession APIs in a way similar to what you describe. If you're using CocoaPods it's possible to use AFNetworking's AFURLSession APIs without necessarily importing the rest of the library. Otherwise taking a look at the code is a good way to see how to do what you want.